# Is archiving the entire filesystem from the root an effective backup strategy?

Tags: backup, tar

I am looking at my server through WinSCP and thinking I could tar the lot, save locally, then if starting a fresh identical server later down the line, re-upload and overwrite saving me the initial set up each time?

Comment: Would you like to clone a machine?

Comment: Only have a 'clone' on hand in the sense that if I start a fresh VPS instance, I don't have to go through the process of setting up the system by entering commands you might find in a secure setup tutorial again and again, install apache, set up sites etc etc. Just 'cloned' enough to accomplish that really.

Comment: What kind of OS are we talking about? Please edit your question and expand on the usecase so we can help you.

Comment: I would strongly recommend against this idea. Backing up `/etc`, sure. But backing up `/`, you're going to run into lots of issues. Subverting your OS package manager causes problems.

Comment: I backup / (using rsync instead of tar) and don't have any issues. After the drive holding / failed, I successfully restored it by reversing the rsync. Caveats: I make a copy of the mbr and have no databases running with files on the partition. That said, this is not a good way to provision servers.

Answer (score 1):

No, `ssh user@server sudo tar cf - / | dd of=server_clone.tar` (or even worse, `tar cf /everything.tar /` and then copy the file off) is not likely to be an efficient way to produce a "clone" down the road, although it may be a stopgap measure if you're worried about soon-to-fail hardware or a security incident.

Some problems:

- `/proc` will give a lot of warnings as you try to traverse it, and cannot be usefully restored
- `/var` and user home directories contain "cache" information that may be irrelevant if you back it up and later restore it

Since you've tagged the question "debian", you have a package-manager and a filesystem convention; assuming you're using it and following it, it would help to take advantage of it.

To get a list of all installed packages (save to a text file):

```
dpkg-query -l | grep '^ii'
```

To back up configuration information for reference (*not* necessarily to restore verbatim!):

```
tar cf config_data.tar /etc /root
```

To back up locally-installed software (and its source-code):

```
tar cf local_soft.tar /opt /usr/local /usr/src
```

To back up program data (depending on exactly what you have installed; note that databases may need to be shutdown to be in a consistent state; `mysqldump` or `pg_dump` will produce a much smaller backup, can be compressed, if the database is running):

```
tar cf daemon_data.tar  /var/www  /srv  /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/postgresql
```

To back up user data:

```
tar cf user_data.tar   /home
```

or maybe

```
tar cf user_data.tar `cut -d : -f 6 /etc/passwd`
```